# Book: A young girl wakes from stasis on another planet

Tags: story-identification, books

I read the first half or so of a book somewhere around 1997-99 when I was about 10-12 years old. I think it was old already then.

As I remember it, it's about a young girl who awakens at the spaceship"s destination after being in stasis for a very long time (50-500 years). She learns from the ship's AI that her friend, a young boy I believe, woke up around 15-20 years before her. She then starts exploring this new planet.

That's about as far as I got.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is an interesting question so far, but if you should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for a good story-identification question you might find there are some more details you can add to your question.